# Associate an empty git commit with files

Tags: git

I know that you can use

```
git commit --allow-empty
```

to put a commit with no actual file changes into the repository.

The problem I have is that I need to be able to create such empty commits that are associated with various file(s) in the repository. In other words, I want to be able to put in some empty commits for which

```
git log -- <filename>
```

will display the commit, but I can't figure out a way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't an empty commit by definition not related to any file?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jeff: What is it use for to make a empty commit?

Comment: @Carl I'm trying to make an empty commit related to specific files.

Comment: @Kit Basically, I want to record some meta history about certain files in the form of a git commit. So an empty commit that isn't associated with any files doesn't help. For various reasons (including the type and format of the data I'm putting in the log) using `git notes` or putting the file names in the log aren't helpful.

Answer (score 7):

From `git log --help`:

```
[--] <path>...
    Show only commits that affect any of the specified paths.
```

You want `git log <path>...` to show a commit that does *not* affect the specified paths. That's not going to happen.

What you can do, however, is put the filenames in the commit message and then use `git log --grep=<filename>`.

Maybe you do not want it in the commit message? Then put it into the commit notes: `git notes add -m <filename>`. You may have to write a small script to grep for notes, but git plumbing should make that fairly easy.

Comment: I'm not asking for the behavior of `git log` to change -- I want it to show the affected paths. What I'm looking for is a way to tell git to consider path X an affected path for an empty commit.

Comment: @Jeff: @drizzd and Carl Norum are quite correct - an empty commit (in this sense) *by definition* introduces no changes, so there are no "affected paths".  There's no way to do what you want without changing the behaviour of `git log`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are also mentioning `git log`, but as I said, I'm not asking to change its behavior. What I was hoping for was a way to tell `git commit` to mark certain paths as affected, even if the diff is null. Then all other `git` subcommands would do the right thing in terms of displaying affected paths, including `git log`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this can't be done is that for git, a commit is a snapshot of the state of all of the files in the project at that point, and the affected files are later *inferred* by comparing a commit to its parent. (Affected files are just those files that differ between the two.) So there's no way to artificially mark a path as affected, because a commit doesn't actually store that information directly.

One thing you could do is change the file permissions (say, set or unset group-writable) on the paths in question--that would be captured as a change, even though the file content is the same. And you could always have two adjacent commits--one which changes the permissions and the other to change them back--if you don't want the permissions to remain altered. It's a bit messy, but it would work, especially if the file permissions aren't important in your case.